# Rake Spec Command not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, rspec

I need to move an ruby site from staging to production...need to check rake spec but when I use rake spec command I am getting message "Your Ruby Version is 1.9.3 but your gem file specified is 2.0.0.."

I have even uninstalled and installed again Heroku Tool belt but still it shows same error...

The ruby version is 1.9.3 in my system(Heroku `/ruby-1.9.3` )

Is there any way to update the version or fix this error...

In my Gem file the ruby version is 2.0.0 but if i change it to 1.9.3 it shows error doesn't get uploaded...

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
# ruby line 
ruby '2.0.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.2'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem will solve with the following way...

Firstly remove the GemFile.lock.

And then bundle install on your production server.

Let me know with your comment, what happens with these way ?